# How to compare two XSD files?

Tags: c#, xml, tfs, xsd

I have two XSD files, which are supposed to be the same. One is stored locally on the machine and one is retrieved from the network where it is stored. I run this test on the local machine, and naturally the test succeeds. But when i run the same build on the TFS (Team Foundation Server), the test fails. I am finding it hard to reason why. The way i am comparing is:

```
public bool compareFunc(string schema1, string schema2) 

bool passed = true;

XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();

doc1.Load(schema1);
doc2.Load(schema2);

string s1 = doc1.innerXML;
string s2 = doc2.innerXML;

for(int i=0; i< s1.length; i++){


if(_s2.Substring(i) != _s1.Substring(i)) { passed = false; }

}

return passed;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess the files on your server have different space or newline characters. That way the content of the strings are different, but the *meaning* of the file is the same.

There're 2 ways to do this. The first way is loop through the xml content, element by element, attribute by attribute, to compare. The second way is save each xml document to a new string, which has the effect of standardizing the layout.

And by the way, to compare 2 strings, you'd use `(s1==s2)`. So your current implementation (which is not working) effectively can be simplified to just a few lines:

```
bool compare(string s1, string s2){
    XmlDocument x1 = new XmlDocument(), x2 = new XmlDocument();
    x1.Load(s1);
    x2.Load(s2);
    return x1.InnerXml == x2.InnerXml;
}
```

Comment: implementing your solution. will let you know the outcome once done.

Comment: Ok i noticed this when i manually compare the two files in Notepad++: AN example: <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/> vs <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" /> in the two files. Which is the case of extra white space character being added somehow.

Comment: You should be carefull with this. This only works if both shema files have their XML  nodes in the exact same order, which is not always the case. Also use Equals for string compare.

Answer (score 1):

You may forgot check s1 and s2 length, as your for is only iterating on s1.length.